# Conversion of a transformer into an electromagnet

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism

Is it possible to convert a voltage transformer into an electromagnet by connecting a small DC voltage source to its primary side?

Answer (score 6):

Just applying DC to a transformer will make a very poor electromagnet, because of the design of the transformer's iron core.

The core is designed to give a continuous loop of iron from one side of the coils to the other.  Rectangular transformers have two loops, giving a squared-off figure of eight.  Toroidal transformers use an iron ring.  Both are designed to keep the magnetism inside the transformer, which makes it more efficient.

But since very little magnetism leaks out, it won't be much use as an electromagnet.

Answer (score 6):

You would have to remove part of the core to open the magnetic circuit.

Most 50/60Hz power transformers have E-I laminations, but they are interleaved (alternating E and I on opposite sides) so you would have to saw and/or grind off part of the core material without damaging the winding, more or less ONE of the two possible lines shown here (lamination drawing from [here](http://www.nyp.com.hk/ei_lam.html)):

[image]

Comment: Look carefully at the transformer construction. The "E" and the "I" are often separate pieces. If that is the case, the "I" can be removed without sawing.